# How to fire CKEditor 4.x from inside jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have downloaded the latest CKEditor version but there is a missing adapters/jquery.js file and I cannot fire it from inside jquery using ckeditor function any more (this is how it worked in previous CKEditor versions).
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery adapter](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10281) is on the go, and will be released along with CKEditor 4.2 within a few days.